# calculate all permutations including all sub-lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, permutation

If I have a list for example:

```
my_list = [a,b,c,d]
```

How can I calculate all permutations **including** the permutations of **all** sub-groups. The partial result for this example would be:

```
permutations = [a,b,c,d,ab,ba,ac,ca,...,abc,acb,abd,...,abcd,abdc,acdb,...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate a size over a range from 1 to the length of `my_list` and use `itertools.permutations` to get all permutations for the given size:

```
from itertools import permutations
my_list = ['a','b','c','d']
[''.join(p) for i in range(1, len(my_list) + 1) for p in permutations(my_list, i)]
```

This returns:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', 'cd', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'abc', 'abd', 'acb', 'acd', 'adb', 'adc', 'bac', 'bad', 'bca', 'bcd', 'bda', 'bdc', 'cab', 'cad', 'cba', 'cbd', 'cda', 'cdb', 'dab', 'dac', 'dba', 'dbc', 'dca', 'dcb', 'abcd', 'abdc', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'adbc', 'adcb', 'bacd', 'badc', 'bcad', 'bcda', 'bdac', 'bdca', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cbad', 'cbda', 'cdab', 'cdba', 'dabc', 'dacb', 'dbac', 'dbca', 'dcab', 'dcba']
```

Answer (score 0):

With the product() function of the itertools library you can generate all possible strings in a given range and with given elements:

```
import itertools

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for i in itertools.product(list, repeat=4):
    print("".join(x for x in i)
```

The code outputs all 4 character long strings that can be made with the letters a-d.